# Ionic 3 folder structuring

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

In ionic 1, i separate my folder in module based like this

```
user
  html
  - user-list.html
  - user-login.html
  - user-profile.html
  - user-edit-profile.html

  scss
  - ....
```

So, in ionic 2 is following the best folder structuring practice?

```
user-list
- user-list.html
- user-list.scss
- user-list.compoment.ts
- user-list.module.ts

user-login
...

user-profile
...

user-edit-profile
....
```

or should i create a user module folder as a parent folder for all user page?

Comment: See this [sample app](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the default folder structure which is generated by using `CLI`. That is the best and most common way of using Ionic.And also recommended by the Ionic team.

It is like this:

```
pages
    user-list
    - user-list.html
    - user-list.scss
    - user-list.ts
    - user-list.module.ts
```

In addition to the `pages` where you will have `providers`, `components`, `models`  and  `pipes` folder structures too.